# Is there an API for Poloniex Lending Fees?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, accounting, poloniex

I'm attempting to reconcile trading activity across accounts on several crypto trading platforms including Poloniex.

Poloniex provides the following API https://poloniex.com/support/api/

Using this api I've sourced:

- Buys & Sells - **returnTradeHistory**
- Transfers - **returnDepositsWithdrawals**
- Loan Earnings - **returnLendingHistory**

I've noticed the following two issues:

1. Lending Fees that are available on the Trade History page in poloniex are not returned via the **returnTradeHistory** endpoint.
2. Loan Earnings via **returnLendingHistory** isn't returning all records regardless of limit parameter.

I can survive the Loan Earnings issues by manually exporting since I rarely lend.

The missing Lending Fees however are vary annoying. If anyone knows of a hidden Endpoint, or an argument I need to pass to **returnTradeHistory** let me know.

Thanks

Comment: What is the **Ticket#** & was the **official Customer facing Representative's response** from Poloniex Support Center >>> https://poloniex.freshdesk.com/support/home ?

Comment: @user3666197 Ticket #402758. No response yet. Its just 3 days old.

Comment: I'm going to be using [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) until there is a better way to get this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still no official reply from Poloniex, but this is a gist of what's working for me.

http://www.currencyprospector.com/2017/08/reconciling-accounts.html

Basically web scraping with Python Selenium complete with login and 2factor auth.

Would be great if Poloniex provided an official API solution.